# how to insert multi value data to database in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to store multiple data to database because i have 2 select option with same name. i've following some tutorial from google and youtube but i still can't figured out how to do it.

Table structure:

`id | nama_mapel | guru_id | kode_mapel | ki_kd_id` |

I have view like this, there's 2 select option with same name:

```
 <input type="text" name="nama_mapel[]">

    <input type="text" name="kode_mapel[]">

<select type="text" name="guru_id[]">
   <option value disable>Pilih Guru</option>
    @foreach ($guru as $item)
   <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->nama_guru }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>

<select name="ki_kd_id[]">
   <option value disable>Pilih Kompetensi Dasar</option>
      @foreach ($komp_dasar as $kd)
        <option value="{{ $kd->id }}">{{ $kd->kompetensi }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>

<select type="text" name="ki_kd_id[]">
     <option value disable>Pilih Kompetensi Inti</option>
       @foreach ($komp_inti as $ki)
         <option value="{{ $ki->id }}">{{ $ki->kompetensi }}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $nama_mapel = $request->nama_mapel;
    $guru_id = $request->guru_id;
    $kode_mapel = $request->kode_mapel;
    $ki_kd_id = $request->ki_kd_id;

    foreach ($nama_mapel as $row => $key){
      $data= [
        'nama_mapel' => $nama_mapel[$row],
        'guru_id' => $guru_id[$row],
        'kode_mapel' => $kode_mapel[$row],
        'ki_kd_id' => $ki_kd_id[$row],
      ];
      DB::table('mapel')->insert($data);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The update method allows you to insert multiple rows at once. You can do that rather than multiple calls in foreach.

Comment: Is that a good thing to do?

Comment: Well, it means you can get rid of the foreach loop, and only send one query to the database. It's up to you to determine if that's a good thing. Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#insert-statements).

Comment: Also, it's a really bad idea, from a standards point of view, to write `$row => $key` as that's not what you are storing. `$row` is actually the key, and `$key` is the value for that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out how to do this.

For view it like this, only use array [] in ki_kd_id name. The reason is because the others is same. I have duplication for all fields except ki_kd_id.

```
<input type="text" name="nama_mapel">

    <input type="text" name="kode_mapel">

<select type="text" name="guru_id">
   <option value disable>Pilih Guru</option>
    @foreach ($guru as $item)
   <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->nama_guru }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>

<select name="ki_kd_id[]">
   <option value disable>Pilih Kompetensi Dasar</option>
      @foreach ($komp_dasar as $kd)
        <option value="{{ $kd->id }}">{{ $kd->kompetensi }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>

<select type="text" name="ki_kd_id[]">
     <option value disable>Pilih Kompetensi Inti</option>
       @foreach ($komp_inti as $ki)
         <option value="{{ $ki->id }}">{{ $ki->kompetensi }}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

and for the controller, it will be like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->ki_kd_id as $value){
        if ($value) {
            DB::table('mapel')->insert([
                'nama_mapel' => $request->nama_mapel,
                'guru_id' => $request->guru_id,
                'kode_mapel' => $request->kode_mapel,
                'ki_kd_id' => $value,
            ]);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Use foreach to loop the request based on how many ki_kd_id that the request have. and then for the value just use $value as representative of ki_kd_id